# mysql enum error: 1067 what is the mistake?

Tags: mysql

```
Errore
query SQL:

CREATE TABLE  `hospital_jqm`.`users` (

`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`name` VARCHAR( 80 ) NOT NULL ,
`surname` VARCHAR( 80 ) NOT NULL ,
`address` VARCHAR( 80 ) NOT NULL ,
`birth_place` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
`province` VARCHAR( 5 ) NOT NULL ,
`birth_date` DATE NOT NULL ,
`sex` ENUM(  'male',  'female' ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '''male''',
`case` ENUM(  'politrauma',  'cardiologico',  'neurologico' ) NOT NULL DEFAULT      '''politrauma'''
) ENGINE = MYISAM CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

 Messaggio di MySQL: 

 #1067 - Invalid default value for 'sex'
```

I tried to create this table but I received this error.why?where is the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `'''male'''` it should be `'male'`.

Answer (score 1):

You've got extra quotes in there. Change to this:

```
sex ENUM('male',  'female') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'male'
```

You were specifying a default value that was not in the list, ie `'male'` (with literal quotes included in the value) rather than `male`

Answer (score 1):

try not using triple quotes..the following worked fine for me..

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (

`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`name` VARCHAR( 80 ) NOT NULL ,
`surname` VARCHAR( 80 ) NOT NULL ,
`address` VARCHAR( 80 ) NOT NULL ,
`birth_place` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
`province` VARCHAR( 5 ) NOT NULL ,
`birth_date` DATE NOT NULL ,
`sex` ENUM(  'male',  'female' ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  'male',
`case` ENUM(  'politrauma',  'cardiologico',  'neurologico' ) NOT NULL DEFAULT      'politrauma'
) ENGINE = MYISAM CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```